# refer to vector element in R

Tags: r, loops, vector

I have a dataframe of survey data, and I want to get relative frequencies from it.

I made a vector of unique genus names from the file:

```
> CoralGenera <- unique(dfrm$V5)
```

Then for each element(Genus) in the vector(CoralGenera), I want to run this function:

```
> mean(dfrm$V5 == "Genus")
```

But it's getting each string saved as an element in the vector to be used in the function that is holding me up.

I tried:

```
> for (Genus in CoralGenera){
   CGrfreq <- c(CGrfreq,mean(dfrm$Genus == Genus))}
```

Which ran, but returned a vector with more elements than CoralGenera

I've been trying to use lapply() instead to avoid copying, but can't get it to work:

```
> lapply(seq_along(CoralGenera), mean(dfrm$Genus == Genus))

> lapply(Genus(CoralGenera), mean(dfrm$Genus == "Genus"))

> lapply(CoralGenera, mean(dfrm$Genus == x))

> lapply(CoralGenera, mean(dfrm$Genus == CoralGenera[v]))
```

Each time it returns an error message like this: 
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'mean(dfrm$Genus == Genus)' is not a function, character or symbol

This is my first time writing a code like this in R, so any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: `lapply(CoralGenera, function(x) mean(dfrm$Genus[ dfrm$Genus %in% x] ))`.  Easier would be `with(dfrm, aggregate(Genus, V5, mean))`. Could also use `tapply` if you wanted a vector instead of a dataframe. The construction `dfrm$Genus == x` is going to return a logical vector which `mean` will coerce to 0's and 1's rather than values.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from what you want the mean. Try one of this:

```
sapply(CoralGenera, function(genus) mean(dfrm$Genus[dfrm$V5 == genus]))
sapply(CoralGenera, function(genus) mean(dfrm$V5[dfrm$V5 == genus]))
```